# $\frac{dy}{dx} - e^{x-y} + e^y = 0 $

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential

how can I solve the given first order differential equation:
$ \frac{dy}{dx} - e^{x-y} + e^y = 0 $

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Hi Paul! Why are you not able to solve this differential equation? Can you kindly show your efforts?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with ODE's but isn't this what you are looking for? https://www.symbolab.com/solver/ordinary-differential-equation-calculator/%5Cfrac%7Bdy%7D%7Bdx%7D-e%5E%7Bx-y%7D%2Be%5E%7Bx%7D%3D0

Comment: @AlexHal: The last term is $e^y$, not $e^x$ which makes it difficult

Comment: The substitution $u = e^y$ transforms the given ODE into a Riccati equation.  If software is to be trusted, it has [a rather complicated solution](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=u%27+%2B+u%5E2+%3D+e%5Ex) in terms of Bessel functions.

Answer (score 3):

How about multiplying the equation by $e^y$, then call $z=e^y$. You get:
$$e^y\frac{dy}{dx}+(e^y)^2=e^x$$
then:$$\frac{dz}{dx}=e^y\frac{dy}{dx}$$ so:$$\frac{dz}{dx}+z^2=e^x$$
Is this something you can solve?

Comment: I was trying this way, yesterday. but I can't continue.

Comment: @Paulpalmer why did you not write this in your question?

Comment: @the_candyman
cause I thought it is wrong.

Comment: @Paulpalmer if it was the right answer, then you would never posted the question, right? So it is important to post **everything**

Comment: then see @FredH comment about the solution. Also make sure the initial equation is correct

Comment: However, +1 for the answer

Comment: @the_candyman thanks